# Exposing the existence of inbox emails to drive-by users

Tags: discussion, user-interface, email-notification, testing

We're soon going to start split testing a new feature: adding a checkbox by the answer field that allows users to opt-in to receive unread inbox items via email.

> [image: inbox email opt-in on answer]

To be clear:

- This will roll out as a split test first, to see its impact on inbox email subscriptions as well as answer submission
- It will only apply to **logged-in users who are not currently subscribed to inbox emails**. Anonymous and unregistered users will not see this checkbox, and users who have already signed up for inbox emails will not see this checkbox
- The box is **unchecked by default** (this is an **opt-in** feature, not an opt-out one).

### So, what are we trying to solve?

Many users' first action on the site is to post an answer. Many of *those* users don't necessarily come back to the site; some don't come back at all, and some come back but aren't logged in because they're on a different device from where they posted.

We want to make sure that these users have the best chance they can to know when the community has interacted with their post. Comments on answers can provide valuable information about how to make the post better, introduce users to the notion of editing, provide a feeling of welcome, and teach new users how Stack Exchange is different from traditional forums. So we'd like to try letting users know that we'll notify them when someone interacts with their posts.

### This may look familiar to you; that's because we already have something similar in place when you ask a question.

We've long had an inbox email prompt on the Ask Question page, since we know that most people want to know as soon as they have a new answer on a question. Here's what that prompt currently looks like:

> [image: inbox email opt-in on ask question page]

The change we'll be testing is taking this UI element and behavior from the Ask Question page, and applying it to answers as well.

We just wanted to give you a heads up in case you hear someone talking about it, or you sometimes see the checkbox and sometimes don't.

Comment: Very interesting! I suspect lots of people will like this feature, yet it doesn't "bug" those of us who don't want it.

Comment: What do the emails look like?  Do they contain the full comments?  Do they just have a link saying 'you've got some new responses'?

Comment: @Keen It's very similar to your actual inbox on the site. Site icon, indicator of what type of response, post title as a link, and an excerpt of the reply.